# I want the new cars: "Je veux les nouvelles voitures" or "Je veux la nouvelles voitures" Not obviously just gender/number agreement so read please!

Tags: grammaire, de

If an adjective comes before its noun then **des** becomes **de** like this: J'ai acheté de nouveaux pantalons. Does this rule apply to **les** as well or does the old "gender and number has to agree" rule takes the cake this time?

Comment: That's a nice inference to make, but the issue here is that "de" in "de nouvelle voitures" isn't the singular of "des", it's just the preposition/partitive marker without a definitive article to merge with.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither **la* nouvelles voitures*, nor **le* nouvelles voitures*.

The singular of *des* (indefinite article) is not *de* but *un* / *une*.

*Des/de* can also be partitive articles, along with *du*, *de la*.

- Indefinite article:

> *J'ai acheté des nouveaux pantalons.* Singular: *J'ai acheté un nouveau pantalon.*
> *Je veux des nouvelles voitures.* → *Je veux une nouvelle voiture.*

- Definite article:

> *J'ai acheté les nouveaux pantalons.* Singular: *J'ai acheté le nouveau pantalon.*
> *Je veux les nouvelles voitures.* → *Je veux la nouvelle voiture.*

- Partitive article:

> J'ai acheté de nouveaux pantalons. No partitive singular (or would be *j'ai acheté du nouveau pantalon*), should use an definite or indefinite article.

> Je veux de nouvelles voitures. → Ditto

Comment: I think pantalons is countable so it can only take the "indefinite article des" and not the "partitive des" so your answer is really confusing to me. Although I'm a newbie so that's that.

Comment: Pantalons (plural) is uncountable in *j'ai acheté **de** nouveaux pantalons* thanks to the prepended adjective. *J'ai acheté **de** pantalons* doesn't work. Note that classifying the articles that way is part of the traditional French grammar but it's no surprise it can be confusing in some cases. Here is an alternative approach: [Claude Muller, Indéfinis et partitifs en français](https://journals.openedition.org/scolia/1436)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends :
If brand A release a new car model, and you want **one** of the many car released in this model, you say "Je veux **la** nouvelle voiture".

If you want many car (from the same new model, or many different model) you'll say "Je veux **les** nouvelle**s** voiture**s**"

And if you just want a new car, any one, because the old one doesn't fit anymore, you'll say "Je veux **une** nouvelle voiture"

But to be more precise on your question, for the trousers, you can use "J'ai acheté **les** nouveaux pantalons" (many) but can't use "J'ai acheté **le** nouveau**x** pantalon**s**" (many).

You have to match number first, then gender.

You'll use "J'ai acheté **le** nouveau pantalon" when single.

"Il/Elle" => "Il**s**/Elle**s**" have plural gender. But "Le/La" only have "Les".

So by matching number first, you'll lose the gender information.